# Woocommerce - Alternative for woocommerce_locate_template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin based on woocommerce and as a part of the I had to override the default template file location of woocommerce. I mean I am looking to have a custom woocommerce template loaded from my plugin.

For doing this I read about woocommerce_locate_template in woocommerce based on this [article](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/), but I noticed that the same function has been deprecated as per this [link](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_locate_template.html). Now I am wondering what could be an alternative function for this.

My whole intention was to change the default woocommerce template loading location to my plugin folder. Any help in resolving this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

woocommerce_locate_template function is deprecated in favor of wc_locate_template: you can read the code [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_locate_template.html#199-238).

However, if you are looking for the **filter**, it's still **woocommerce_locate_template** and takes three arguments:

1. **$template** that is the result of the wp core function locate_template
2. **$template_name** that is only the filename
3. **$template_path** that is the woocommerce path for templates

So you can check if the $template_name is what you want to intercept and change the path if true, like this

```
function intercept_wc_template($template, $template_name, $template_path) {
    if ($template_name == 'that_template.php') {
        $template = 'the/path/of/your/plugin/template.php';
    }
    return $template;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'intercept_wc_template', 20, 3);
```

I've not tested it, so sorry for any possible syntax error :)

Hope it helps!

*-- Update 1: I forgot a semicolon :P --*
*-- Update 2: I made a mistake! --*

Comment: Thanks for you response Lorenzo Zottar. I tried your code and below is the code, but I can see there are no changes happening in the product template.

Comment: here is the code I tried  `function intercept_wc_template($template, $template_name, $template_path) {
    if ($template_name == 'content-single-product.php') {
        //um_product_path is the plugin path
        
        $template = locate_template(um_product_path.'woocommerce/single-product/content-single-product.php');
    }
    return $template;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'intercept_wc_template', 20, 3);`

Comment: Try to add `var_dump($template);` before the return $template to debug if the path is correct and if the if statements works. 
The string will appear at the top of your page when you enter in a woocommerce page.
The filter works, so it could be or a problem with your path or a problem in the if statement :)

Comment: I have just checked the var_dump in the product page. Noticed that the var_dump string refers to original woocommerce template folder or my theme woocommerce folder but not my plugin folder anywhere.

Comment: So the problem is in the if statement: change the var_dump in `var_dump($template_name);` and go to the page that you want to intercept and check the exact name of the template.
However i've made a mistake, you don't have to use locate_template, but simply override the $template variable: i've just tested it on my local machine. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lorenzo Zottar. Finally I got it, the problem is with the new template location where I missed to mention folder name 'single-product'. I am able to see the changes after changing this. :)

Comment: Glad to helped you :) If you like, check my answer to be right, for future users that will have the same problem :)

Comment: I just did it. Thanks again for your time on this.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, just a quick question in the same conext. Is there a way to override the entire template folder location?

Comment: I guess you could use the filter 'woocommerce_template_path' to override the default template path, but I don't know if it will break something for others plug-ins or themes.

Answer (score 6):

I had to modify the above code in order to get it to correctly match the template file I needed, which in my case was "variable.php".

$template_name needs to be the full woocommerce root path, see below:

See the amended code below:

```
function intercept_wc_template($template, $template_name, $template_path) {
    if ($template_name == 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php') {
        $template = 'wp-content/themes/theme-name/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php';
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'intercept_wc_template', 20, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone struggle with this as of 2021, worth mention that the **filter** `'woocommerce_locate_template'` **does not filter all templates** inside woocommerce folder. Instead, You need to filter 2 other functions:

```
add_filter('wc_get_template', 'entex_wc_get_template', 20, 5);
add_filter('wc_get_template_part', 'entex_wc_get_template_part', 20, 3);
```

For example, The root woocommerce template `content-single-product.php` must be filtered with wc_get_template_part.

This is working for our plugin:

```
function template_base(){
    return untrailingslashit(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )) .'/templates/';
}

function entex_wc_get_template($template, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path){

    /* custom theme templates has priority */
    if(strpos($template, '/themes/') !== FALSE) return $template;

    static $cache = array();
    if(isset($cache[$template_name])) return $cache[$template_name];
    
    $plugin_template = wc_locate_template($template_name, WC()->template_path(), $this->template_base());
    if($plugin_template && file_exists($plugin_template)){
        $template = $plugin_template;
        $cache[$template_name] = $template;
    }
    return $template;
}

function entex_wc_get_template_part($template, $slug, $name){
    
    /* custom theme templates has priority */
    if(strpos($template, '/themes/') !== FALSE) return $template;
    
    $template_name = '';
    if($name){
        $template_name = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";
    } else if($slug){
        $template_name = "{$slug}.php";
    }
    if(!$template_name) return $template;
    
    static $cache = array();
    if(isset($cache[$template_name])) return $cache[$template_name];
    
    $plugin_template = template_base().$template_name;
    if($plugin_template && file_exists($plugin_template)){
        $template = $plugin_template;
        $cache[$template_name] = $template;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

This is ripped out of the PHP class and pasted here so hopefully the code is not broken.

We recommend to register the templates for cleaner performance, if you only use a few, and add something like this early in the functions:

```
if(!in_array($template_name, array(
    'archive-product.php',
    'content-product.php',
    'content-product-cat.php',
    'content-single-product.php',
    'content-widget-product.php',
    'checkout/form-checkout.php',
    'checkout/thankyou.php',
    'loop/loop-start.php',
    'loop/loop-end.php'
))) return $template;
```