# Woocommerce: Custom email class can't find the template in plugin

Tags: class, email, woocommerce

I'm making a custom status for Woocommerce "ready for pick-up", with an associated email.
This is added via a custom plugin, and everything works fine - except that I can't seem to get the path to the template right.

My folder structure for the plugin is lockoloop-customizer > templates > backend > emails.
In backend, I have the ready-pickup-status.php that defines the status and calls the class:

```
function add_customer_ready_order_email( $email_classes ) {
    require_once LCLPC_ADMIN_TEMPLATES_DIR . 'emails/class-wc-ready-for-pickup-email.php';
    $email_classes['WC_Ready_For_Pickup_Email'] = new WC_Ready_For_Pickup_Email();
    return $email_classes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_customer_ready_order_email' );


function custom_email_template_path( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
    error_log('template');
    if ($template_name === 'customer-ready-order.php' || $template_name === 'plain/customer-ready-order.php') {
        $template = LCLPC_ADMIN_TEMPLATES_DIR . 'emails/'. $template_name;
    } 
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'custom_email_template_path', 10, 3 );
```

The filter doesn't seem to trigger at all (nothing in the error log).

In emails, I have class-wc-ready-for-pickup-email.php (the class) and customer-ready-order.php (the template).

This is part of the code for the class:

```
class WC_Ready_For_Pickup_Email extends WC_Email {
        public function __construct() {
            $this->template_html  = 'customer-ready-order.php';
```

This is the constant I use, which works everywhere else:

```
define( 'LCLPC_PLUGIN_FILE',            __FILE__ );

// Plugin Folder Path
define( 'LCLPC_PLUGIN_DIR',             plugin_dir_path( LCLPC_PLUGIN_FILE ) );

// Backend Folder PATH
define( 'LCLPC_ADMIN_TEMPLATES_DIR',    LCLPC_PLUGIN_DIR.'templates/backend/' );
```

I saw [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986892/custom-email-template-issue-in-woocommerce) solved it by moving the template to its theme folder, but I'd like to keep it in my plugin, since it's linked to the custom status I'm adding.
So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446556/woocommerce-alternative-for-woocommerce-locate-template

Comment: Isn't that the same as my custom_email_template_path function?  (which doesn't seem to trigger at all)

Comment: The key difference between these functions is in their primary purpose. wc_get_template() is used for loading template files and rendering their contents, while woocommerce_locate_template() is used for finding the path to a template file without actually loading it. You might use wc_get_template() when you want to include and render the template, and woocommerce_locate_template() when you just need to know the file's location.

Comment: Aaaah, so you were referring to the last answer, not the most upvoted solution? Thanks, I'll have a closer look.